# How can change the value of a member of a base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have three classes:

```
class Operation{
public:
    virtual bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol) = 0;
    pair<int, int> pair_routes;
};

class OperationR : public Operation{
public:
    OperationR(){};
    bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol);
    pair<int, int> pair_routes;
};

class OperationD : public Operation{
public:
    OperationD(){};
    bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol);
    pair<int, int> pair_routes;
};
```

The value of `pair_routes` changes inside the `execute()` function.

In the `main()` function, I create a `vector` of class `Operation` like this:

```
vector<Operation*> operations;
    
OperationR* opr = new OperationR();
operations.push_back(opr);
    
OperationD* opd = new OperationD();
operations.push_back(opd);
    
Operation* op = operations[0];
Solution s1, s2;
op->execute(s1, s2);   // line 1
    
cout << op->pair_routes.first;
```

There is no problem in the compilation, but even if the value of `pair_routes` changes in line 1, it returns the value 0. I tried to initialize this member in the base class with different values, and each time the program returns this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived classes are declaring their own `pair_routes` members that *shadow* (ie, hide) the `pair_routes` member of the base `Operation` class.

When you execute `op->execute()`, `op` is pointing at an `OperationR` object, so it is calling `OperationR::execute()`, which is then modifying the `OperationR::pair_routes` data member.  But then afterwards, you are display the `Operation::pair_routes` data member instead, which was not modified.

Get rid of the shadowing `pair_routes` data members, you don't need them.  The derived classes have access to the `pair_routes` data member of the base class.

```
class Operation{
public:
    virtual bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol) = 0;
    pair<int, int> pair_routes;
};

class OperationR : public Operation{
public:
    OperationR() = default;
    bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol) override;
    //pair<int, int> pair_routes; // <-- get rid of this
};

class OperationD : public Operation{
public:
    OperationD() = default;
    bool execute(const Solution& sol, Solution& newSol) override;
    //pair<int, int> pair_routes; // <-- get rid of this
};
```

Comment: Having shadowing variables like these usually also hints at not using (or reading) compiler warnings...